# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: AccessDenied: Access Denied Error while coping object from public s3 bucket to private

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am copying objects from one of the public s3 buckets to private s3 bucket.

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
    return s3.copyObject({
      Bucket: 'XXXXX',
      CopySource: sourceUrl,
      Key: key,
    }).promise();
```

I've two kind of examples of sourceUrl:

1. `elasticbeanstalk-ap-south-A-BCDE/folder_name/Image_name_2022-08-10T12:22:19.351Z.jpg`
2. `elasticbeanstalk-ap-south-A-BCDE/folder_name/Image_name_2022-08-10T12:22:19.jpg`

First one contains two dots in fileName while second contains only one for extension. I am able to copy second object but getting error as mentioned above in first one.

Comment: check the policy of first image, and try making it **public** and try again.

Comment: Hi @sachin, The first image is public as well.